# Failed to verify code signature

Tags: ios, code-signing, testflight

I've been working on this app for a few months now and one of every few builds that I push out through the new Test Flight in iTunes Connect can't be installed, and when I connect my device to my computer to look at the console, I see the error message

> "Failed to verify code signature"

With the supplemental message:

> Entitlements found that are not permitted by provisioning profile

I don't understand why this is an issue only **sometimes**.  I seem to correct the issue by creating a new identical, aside from the build number, version and upload that.

What could I possibly be doing wrong?  The only "entitlement" my app registers for is access to the keychain, but there is no toggle for that in the entitlements potion oft he application identifier on the developer portal.